# iCloud UIDocument opening fails after update on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, uidocument, icloud-documents

I have a simple UIDocument subclass with overriding `load` and `contents` functions.

Before updating on iOS 13 json document was saved in url "*/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~appbundle/Documents/EFB7FCBA96684AC0B101E3CD829E6996.json*"

In current iOS version 13.2.2 (after updating) this document does not open:

```
let cloudDocument: ICloudDocument = ICloudDocument(fileURL: url)
cloudDocument.open { (openSuccess) in
    if openSuccess {
        success()
    } else {
        // in my case openSuccess is false
        failure()
    }
}
```

**Debug information.**

After overriding `handleError` in ICloudDocument

```
override func handleError(_ error: Error, userInteractionPermitted: Bool) {     
    print("userInteractionPermitted - \(userInteractionPermitted)")
    print(error)
}
```

in console:

```
userInteractionPermitted - true
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “EFB7FCBA96684AC0B101E3CD829E6996” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~appbundle/Documents/EFB7FCBA96684AC0B101E3CD829E6996.json}
```

If I use `cloudDocument.read` method in ICloudDocument it works well with receiving data from file, but `open` throws the error.

DocumentState `cloudDocument.documentState` of document is *closed*.

File options:

```
> print(FileManager.default.isWritableFile(atPath: url.path))
true
> print(FileManager.default.isReadableFile(atPath: url.path))
true
```

URLResourceKeys:

```
URLResourceKey.ubiquitousItemIsUploadingKey - true
URLResourceKey.ubiquitousItemIsUploadedKey - false
URLResourceKey.ubiquitousItemUploadingErrorKey - nil
URLResourceKey.ubiquitousItemHasUnresolvedConflictsKey - false
URLResourceKey.isUbiquitousItemKey - true
URLResourceKey.ubiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey - "NSURLUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusCurrent"
```

I found one link about this problem without answer
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/126889

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restaring iOS solved this problem. I think that after updating into iOS 13 and migration, system needs additional reload.